# Prove $\det (A)\le \left(\max_{i,j}|A_{ij}|\right)^n n^{n/2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, hadamard-matrices

> Prove $\det (A)\le \left(\max_{i,j}|A_{ij}|\right)^n n^{n/2}$

How do I prove this as an extension of the Hadamard Inequality? This expression is given as a corollary of the Hadamrd inequality in multiple places, but I'm not able to prove it.

Comment: Hint: the norm of $k^{th}$ column $= \sqrt{A_{1k}^2 + A_{2k}^2 + \cdots + A_{nk}^2}
\le \sqrt{n} \max\limits_{1\le i \le n} |A_{ik}| 
\le \sqrt{n} \max\limits_{1 \le i, j \le n } |A_{ij}|$.